# How can I ensure my dark background (trigged when a menu button opens a modal) covers the entire background?

Tags: javascript, css, background, z-index

I am working on a simple memory game with HTML, CSS, and vanilla JS. On mobile, I have a menu button that triggers a modal and (should) display a dark background behind the modal.

I created a .dark-background class that I apply to my  when the menu button is clicked, and I added a z-index of 1 to the background and a z-index of 2 to the modal. The dark background isn't laying over all elements on the page, though - it seems like the elements with JS logic applied to them display above the dark background. [Here's](https://lexsac.github.io/memory-game/) the link to the site - any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```js
// mobile menu
const openMenuButton = document.getElementById("button__menu");

// when the menu button is clicked 
openMenuButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  stopTimer();

  // if the menu is closed, open it 
  menuModal.setAttribute("data-visible", true);
  body.classList.add('dark-background');
})
```

```css
/* applied to body when modals are visible */

.dark-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: var(--br-sm);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header__gameboard | flex">
    <h1 class="header__title | lowercase text-blue-800">memory</h1>
    <button class="header__button-menu | btn btn-orange" id="button__menu">Menu</button>
    <div class="header__button-group | flex">
      <button class="header__button-restart | btn btn-orange" id="button__restart">Restart</button>
      <button class="header__button-new-game | btn btn-blue" id="button__new-game">New Game</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu modal -->
    <div class="modal flex" id="menu" data-visible="false">
      <button class="header__button-restart | btn btn-orange" id="button__restart">Restart</button>
      <button class="header__button-new-game | btn btn-blue" id="button__new-game">New Game</button>
      <button class="header__button-resume | btn btn-blue" id="button__resume">Resume Game</button>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="game">
      <div class="game__area | grid" id="game">
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="player-info">
      <div class="player__info | grid">
        <div class="player__time | flex">
          <h2>Time</h2>
          <p id="player__time-dynamic">0:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player__moves | flex">
          <h2>Moves</h2>
          <p id="player__moves-dynamic"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- End game modal -->
    <section class="end-results | modal" id="end" data-visible="false">
      <h1 class="end-results__headline | modal-headline">You did it!</h1>
      <p class="end-results__description | modal-description">Game over! Here's how you got on...</p>
      <div class="end-results__player-info end-results__player-info-time | flex modal-info-box">
        <p class="end-results__time">Time Elapsed</p>
        <p class="end-results__time-dyn" id="game-end__time"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="end-results__player-info end-results__player-info-moves | flex modal-info-box">
        <p class="end-results__moves">Moves Taken</p>
        <p class="end-results__moves-dyn" id="game-end__moves"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="end-results__btns | flex">
        <button id="button__restart" class="btn btn-orange">Restart</a>
        <button id="button__new-game" class="btn btn-blue">Setup New Game</a>
      </div>
    </section>

  </main>
</body>
```

I've tried with z-index, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie here, but I think if I understood your question right, you shuld use:

menuModal.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

you can edit css-properties using this concept

- please give me a feedback, if I could help you :)